# appendChild not working in google maps

Tags: javascript, appendchild

Why is element A invisible? It seems that appendChild() function is ignored. I can only see the B element. (element A is visible if I push it inside the controls) :(

```
var a = document.createElement('A');
a.style.width = '50px';
a.style.height = '50px';
a.style.cursor = 'pointer';
a.style.backgroundColor = 'rgba(10,20,30,1.0)';

var b = document.createElement('B'); 
b.style.width = '200px';
b.style.height = '200px';
b.style.backgroundColor = 'rgba(230,230,230,0.6)';

b.appendChild(a);
map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT].push(b);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you have to display both the elements on a `block` level

```
var a = document.createElement('A');
a.style.width = '50px';
a.style.height = '50px';
a.style.cursor = 'pointer';
a.style.backgroundColor = 'rgba(10,20,30,1.0)';
a.style.display = 'block'; //style block level

var b = document.createElement('B'); 
b.style.width = '200px';
b.style.height = '200px';
b.style.backgroundColor = 'rgba(230,230,230,0.6)';
b.style.border = '1px solid black';
b.style.display = 'block'; //style block level

document.body.appendChild(b);
b.appendChild(a);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9rnzbuqh/

Comment: Thank you very much, Mikey! :)

Answer (score 0):

`<a>` is an inline element by default, and you can't set width or height of an inline element. You have to change its `display` to `block`:

```
var a = document.createElement('A');
a.style.width = '50px';
a.style.height = '50px';
a.style.cursor = 'pointer';
a.style.backgroundColor = 'rgba(10,20,30,1.0)';
a.style.display = 'block';

var b = document.createElement('B'); 
b.style.width = '200px';
b.style.height = '200px';
b.style.backgroundColor = 'rgba(230,230,230,0.6)';
b.style.display = 'block';

b.appendChild(a);
map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT].push(b);
```

Comment: How is this a different answer than mine posted a few minutes earlier?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what I was doing. It worked without setting the display style but I had no idea why.

https://jsfiddle.net/9rnzbuqh/78/

```
var c = document.createElement('div');
c.style.height = '263px';
c.style.width = '350px';
c.style.marginLeft = '0px';
c.style.marginTop = '0px';
c.style.backgroundImage = "url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/5/5f/TomandJerryTitleCardc.jpg)";


var d = document.createElement('div');
d.style.background = 'rgba(230,230,230,0.6)';
d.style.paddingBottom = '70px';
d.style.paddingLeft = '40px';
d.style.paddingRight = '40px';
d.appendChild(c);
document.body.appendChild(d);
```

and

```
div {
  width:400px;
}
```